# How can I use dropdowns in a masonry layout?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I am using a layout list with Masonry (and [animOnScroll](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/) on top of it). I want to add bootstrap dropdowns to my list items, but Masonry inserts directly into every dropdown `<li>` DOM node a `style="position: absolute; left: 0px;"`.

I am already overriding animOnScroll CSS rules for `<li>` items (the selector `.grid li{` was matching my dropdown items).

However, I can't figure out how to remove these direct styling properties or why they appear in each dropdown `<li>` as `style="position: absolute; left: 0px;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masonry provides an [item-selector option](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#itemselector) to avoid this kind of issues. I knew it but it turns out that AnimOnScroll add its own options when directly instantiating Masonry. The faulty lines were then, in AnimOnScroll:

```
self.masonry = new Object(new Masonry( self.el, {
                itemSelector: 'li',
                transitionDuration : 0
            } ));
```

It should be instead:

```
self.masonry = new Object(new Masonry( self.el, {
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                transitionDuration : 0
            } ));
```